# Why does map return an empty array?

Tags: perl, dictionary

I have a problem in Perl I don't understand. I stripped it down to this very short code.

Why does Perl's **`map`** function return an empty array? Shouldn't it return an array with 9 `undef`s?

```
sub mySub{
    return;
}

my @arr = (1 .. 9);
my @arr2 = map( mySub($_), @arr );

print @arr . ' ' . @arr2, "\n";
```

It prints "9 0".

It is probably something simple, but <kbd>perldoc</kbd> is not helping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more general answer to your question is this: when `return` is used without an argument, the value it returns depends on the calling context:

```
list context    returns an empty list
scalar context  returns an undefined value
```

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my (@list);
sub mySub { return }
@list = map(       mySub($_), 1..2); print Dumper(\@list);
@list = map(scalar mySub($_), 1..2); print Dumper(\@list);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

Comment: thanks .... the catch is, I didn't know that map calls it in list context.

(this scalar/list context concept still sometimes confuse me in perl :))

Answer (score 7):

You subroutine is **not** returning undef, it is returning an empty list. 9 times and empty list is still an empty list.

Try explicitly returning undef and the output will be different.

Comment: No, you would get a list of 9 empty lists.

Comment: jiggy: I think you cannot have a list of lists in perl. Perl lists are all "flat" and "1-dimensional".

Comment: @karel, Perl can nest data structures to arbitrary depth and complexity (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). Secondly, while Manni's answer (surprisingly) does give the desired output, it doesn't work the way you think. Run this: my @arr2 = map(undef, @arr); and you will get the same result.

Comment: The same as what? You'll get an array containing undef 9 times.

Comment: jiggy: Yes, perl has n-dimensional lists, but it order to get that you'd have to return a list reference from mySub, eg "return [];", because otherwise the lists get flattened.

Comment: Who's talking about more than 1 dimension here?

Comment: @Manni, yeah I know about list flattening, but I concede that I messed up here. Your answer does work. I always use map with a block, so the syntax looked wrong to me, but it ain't.

Comment: jiggy: my subroutine is actually bigger than this one and it would feel wrong to put it just to block. Also, it returned empty lists (which I thought was undef) only is some cases, so the result was not empty array but only smaller array. Anyway thanks both

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub mySub{
    return undef;
}

my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @arr2 = map(&mySub, @arr);

print @arr." ".@arr2;
```

If you need to get list containing undefs, you need to return undef explicitly. The thing is that map calls your mySub in array context (check what wantarray gives you from this sub). return statement essentially gives back an empty list each time your sub is called, which results in empty array in total

Comment: nonono, my code was just a stupid example that did nothing. I don't want to do what you described, I just wanted to have list with 9 undefs. But thanks anyway

Comment: Why is this downmodded?  This is the most sensible answer here.